# How do I get the nltk Stanford Parser to return collapsed Dependencies (not Universal Dependencies)?

Tags: dependencies, nltk, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to use NLTK's StanfordDependencyParser (v 3.9.1) to get dependency parsing output. I understand that currently, it returns Universal Dependencies. 
Is there a way to configure it from NLTK such that it returns Collapsed Dependencies with Propagation? (This used to be the default earlier). I'm only finding ways to do it in JAVA, but no hints as to how this can be done in NLTK. Any help is appreciated, I have spent over a week trying to crack this.